# Output of predict_proba in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Suppose I have a data sample having two classes labeled 0 and 1. When I run `output = clf.predict_proba(X_input)`, each row in `output` consists of 2 columns corresponding to probability of each class.

Does the first column represent probability of class 0 or 1? [The predict_proba method of GradientBoostingClassier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.predict_proba) says:

> "The class probabilities of the input samples. The order of the classes corresponds to that in the attribute classes_."

Does that mean that whichever, 0 or 1, is the first element of the data sample
corresponds to the first column in the output of `predict_proba`?

Answer (score 6):

Generally a classifier will have an attribute named `classes_` this will be populated upon fitting and store the classes. The order of the `predict_proba` method output will be the same as the order in this attribute.

For example:

```
nb = MultinomialNM()
nb.fit(some_gender_data)
nb.classes_
array(['F', 'M'], dtype='<U1')
```

As far as I know all of the classifiers in sklearn have this attribute once fit.